# MongoDB: Assign document objects to field in '$project' stage

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a user collection:

```
[
  {"_id": 1,"name": "John", "age": 25, "valid_user": true}
  {"_id": 2, "name": "Bob", "age": 40, "valid_user": false}
  {"_id": 3, "name": "Jacob","age": 27,"valid_user": null}
  {"_id": 4, "name": "Amelia","age": 29,"valid_user": true}
]
```

I run a `'$facet'` stage on this collection. Checkout this [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ueBz8CD7M6c).
I want to talk about the first output from the facet stage. The following is the response currently:

```
{
  "user_by_valid_status": [
      {
        "_id": false,
        "count": 1
      },
      {
        "_id": true,
        "count": 2
      },
      {
        "_id": null,
        "count": 1
      }
    ]
}
```

However, I want to restructure the output in this way:

```
"analytics": {
    "invalid_user": {
        "_id": false
        "count": 1
    },
    "valid_user": {
        "_id": true
        "count": 2
    },
    "user_with_unknown_status": {
        "_id": null
        "count": 1
    }
}
```

The problem with using a `'$project'` stage along with `'arrayElemAt'` is that the order may not be definite for me to associate an index with an attribute like `'valid_users'` or others. Also, it gets further complicated because unlike the sample documents that I have shared, my collection may not always contain all the three categories of users.

Is there some way I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$switch` conditional operator,

- `$project` to show value part in `v` with _id and count field as object, `k` to put `$switch` condition

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$facet": {
      "user_by_valid_status": [
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": "$valid_user",
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            v: { _id: "$_id", count: "$count" },
            k: {
              $switch: {
                branches: [
                  { case: { $eq: ["$_id", null] }, then: "user_with_unknown_status" },
                  { case: { $eq: ["$_id", false] }, then: "invalid_user" },
                  { case: { $eq: ["$_id", true] }, then: "valid_user" }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "users_above_30": [{ "$match": { "age": { "$gt": 30 } } }]
    }
  },
```

- `$project` stage in root, convert `user_by_valid_status` array to object using `$arrayToObject`

```
  {
    $project: {
      analytics: { $arrayToObject: "$user_by_valid_status" },
      users_above_30: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/msi8Q8tuO84)